# Searching files network drive and logging file names

Tags: search, network-drive

I'm trying to log the filenames of files containing a certain word. The files are across multiple directories in a network drive. I've tried to do it myself but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Which operating system are you running?

Comment: The device thats connected to the network drive is running windows server 2012, i have a laptop with ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I might have been a bit unclear. I meant that i'm trying to log filenames where the name of the file contains a certain word, not the content of the file.

Comment: And you want to get  a list of the filenames (maybe as a text file), rather than manipulate them (edit/copy/rename/delete)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a GUI based solution, then:

- download the excellent (and free) [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/)  which runs on Windows, Linux, mac and BSD.
- install (or use the portable version) and run it
- navigate to the top directory, where you want to start your search
- press Alt+F7 (or use menu item Commands/Search)
- enter the partial file name (the word you want the names to contain)
- when shown the results, click on the button "feed to listbox"
- press Ctrl+A to select all
- right click and select "Copy file/folder path"
- the clipboard now contains a list of file names containing your wor, one per line, with full path

If that sounds like a lot of work, it's because I detailed it step by step. In practise, a few seconds will see it done, and you will find Double Commander to be much more useful than the built in Windows Explorer :-)

Comment: Thanks alot for your solution, this will definately work. Its a server from where i work and i dont have Admin Access. Its definately possible if i ask the administrator but i dont want to Bother them, is there a command prompt solution? If there isnt ill ask them to install this program.

Comment: Btw ur steps are perfectly clear :)

Comment: I am unaware of a command prompt solution, as this is how I would approach it - sorry. You can use a portable version, so as not to disturb your admin.

Comment: That is the solution. Thanks slot and have a Nice day!

Comment: By the way, once you have the list, you can copy/move/rename/edit/delete/zip/FTP one, several, or all files in the list.